How to uncollapse/unfold the HTTP response?
I use reactotron with reactnative on macOS. I have lots of HTTP responses like this, with lot of nested array/object.
It's a lot of time to click on each node to expand. How to display data directly like I can have with console.log(JSON.Stringify( data, undefined, 3)) for example?
My ReactotronConfig.js file
import Reactotron, {networking} from 'reactotron-react-native';

Reactotron.configure() // controls connection & communication settings
  .useReactNative() // add all built-in react native plugins
  .use(networking())
  .connect(); // let's connect!


